# Negative value prediction using gradient bosting with Gaussian distribution in gbm

Tags: r, machine-learning, normal-distribution, boosting

Why does `gbm` specified with Gaussian distribution throw negative values? Can it be controlled or modified if one does not want negative predictions (in `R`)?

Comment: Hi Naive Prestige; welcome to CV. I edited your question because the first and second parts didn't correspond. I plumped for adding 'not' in the second sentence. If that's wrong please edit your question to remove that and correct the apparent mismatch between the two sentences

Comment: Thank you Glen_b! yes the question remains the same.

Comment: I realized I had put in two question at one instance, will put the other question separately.

Answer (score 1):

There are other distributions that don't allow negative values for the predictions.  The gaussian distribution is defined for all values of the mean so you can't guarantee positive predictions.

Comment: Welcome @Ryan You could improve your answer & help the OP (and others) by telling him/her which ones he can use? Perhaps include a short example illustrating how?